Are JNF with identical blocks in different orders considered equal?
I'm working on a linear algebra problem involving JNF and similarity transformations. Here’s the setup: Given a matrix

M = \begin{pmatrix} 7 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 7 & 0 \\ -1 & 4 & 7 \end{pmatrix}

the tasks are as follows:
Determine distinct invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $P^{-1} M P = J$ and $Q^{-1} M Q = J$, where $J$ is a Jordan matrix. Additionally, I'm asked whether there exist distinct invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ and a Jordan form matrix $H$ such that $H \neq J$ and both $A^{-1} M A = H$ and $B^{-1} M B = H$.
I'm wondering if we should interpret the question in terms of the uniqueness of the Jordan Normal Form up to the order of Jordan blocks. If $J$ and $H$ are technically the same JNF but differ in the order of blocks, they could be distinct as matrices (thus satisfying $H \neq J$ as stated). Should I consider this case, or use uniqueness theorem to explain that no such $A$, $B$, and $H$ exist?

I think the question is strict and the answer you should give would be by permitting two blocks. Of course for the invertible matrices you can find one and multiply it by a scalar

@julio_es_sui_glace Thank you. I think H can be constructed simply by reordering, but I don't know how to say distinct A and B exist.

Just take B = 2A

@julio_es_sui_glace how should I find A？ thanks

If you have P it should be easy to have A the rest need to be done by you. If you have no clue, you better reread your course on Jordan
